How to reach Pale forest last golden chest?
I'm trying to open this ward which needs hitting those 6 buttons with green and blue magic quickly within time limit. I'm having a really hard time to hit them before timer expires. I have tried changing horizontal and vertical sensitivity all the way but no luck.
Any help please for my platinum trophy.


This doesn't seem hard, see this video for reference (stating at 13:00):



You can solve it even missing some shots.

i have watched videos but they are not helpful in this regard. what sigil shuld i use, what sensitivty settings should i use? i have tried everything, nothing works for me. these doors are so annoying.

i was able to do it using the slow down spell, otherwise this is not possible on a ps5 using joystick. you can easily do it with mouse but joystick is impossible.

Good for you! Glad you figured out a solution
